# Chutzpah Code Coverage "EnableCodeCoverage": "true" not generating html file

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, chutzpah

I am able to generate the code coverage using the context menu. I would like to generate the coverage file whenever I run the unit test. It tried setting this JSON property **"EnableCodeCoverage": "true"**    but it is not working.

Is that possible?

Regards,
Raaj

Answer (score 0):

You found a bug in Chutzpah! I just [committed a fix](https://github.com/mmanela/chutzpah/commit/e377903976d71911463da19f6266059b6e7b6086) and will include this when I make the next release (probably 3.2.5)

Comment: Thanks! Will wait for the release :)